# Spring 5 and hibernate 4 compatible?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Can you use hibernate 4 with Spring boot 5? I am trying to integrate hibernate 4 with Spring boot 5 since I want to use Hibernate 4 functions and API instead of 5, but I am using Spring boot 5 and getting errors such as conflicting directories between Spring boot Hibernate and custom Hibernate.

I am using Spring 5.2.3 with Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE
and I want to use Hibernate 4.3.x

Comment: I doubt you are using Spring Boot 5.2.3 but rather Spring 5.2.3 with Spring Boot 2.2.4. That being said only HIbernate 5 is supported by Spring 5, so no you cannot use hibernate4 with Spring Boot 2.2 or Spring 5.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the list of supported Libraries for Spring 5.x, we can see Hibernate as 5+

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x

Answer (score 0):

Spring 5x is compatible with hibernate 4x unless you are using it as an implementation of JPA which might not be compatible.

A suggestion would be using the latest hibernate.